# Determine whether current script is running on development or production server

Tags: php, localhost, development-environment, production-environment

I've got scripts that call different URLs depending on if they're processed by my online site (release), or my offline localhost (development).  I'd like to find a quick way to find which is which.

I can come up with a few clunky ways to do this, but is there a definitive, fast, elegant method?  Something like `if(is_offline()) { ... }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. A variable called `$_SERVER["COMPUTERNAME"]` is available on IIS servers, you can use it to determine if the script is running on your development server or production server (*MYMACHINE* vs. *WWW37*).
2. You can also use `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` variable (*localhost* vs. *www.domain.com*).
3. You can also create an empty text file on your development server (careful not to upload it) and use `is_file()` to check if its presence (is_file(".foo") == *true* vs. *false*).
4. You can check for PHP_OS if the operating systems on the two servers are different (*WINNT* vs. *Linux*).
5. You can check for the presence of certain path inside the `__FILE__` constant (*C:/inetpub/wwwroot/website/* vs. */home/www37/*).
6. A variant of 3: `@include("override_server_with_local_config.php");`

Comment: Accepted this one because I'm already using a variant of #3. Didn't really get the definitive answer I was looking for :/.  Thanks anyway though everybody.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to see what hostname the script is running under.

You can look at `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to see if the user requesting the page's IP is 127.0.0.1.

You can ping something on your local network to see if you're connected to it.

You can define a constant at the start of your code which you set to 'release' or 'development' on the appropriate machine.

Comment: and it fails if he's using ipv6.

Comment: It also fails if he's on the international space station, which is just as unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to set a configuration variable somewhere that indicates `production` or `development`.

You could do it by hostname (`localhost` vs `www.foobar.com`), but this is a wonky solution. You may access your app using different host names for testing as well. Therefore, explicit is better than implicit.

Answer (score 0):

a couple of checkings could make it possible

```php
define('IS_LOCAL', !(
  in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], array('localhost','127.0.0.1')) === false &&
  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== '127.0.0.1' &&
  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== '::1'
));
```

Answer (score -1):

One function can Help `get_headers('URL')`.

[get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

Tt fetches all the headers sent by the server. Check returned array to check status of URL. First element of returned array contains URL status.